# Unsupported operand type (s) error when processing audio with deep learning

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning

I want to run a function for processing mp3 file with deep learning. But I get the following error. I looked for solutions for similar errors, but it did not help. What could be the problem?

```
def createSpectrogramsFromAudio():
    genresID = dict()
    files = os.listdir(rawDataPath)
    files = [file for file in files if file.endswith(".mp3")]
    nbFiles = len(files)

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(spectrogramsPath)):
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(spectrogramsPath))
        except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
            if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

    for index,filename in enumerate(files):
        print ("Creating spectrogram for file {}/{}...".format(index+1,nbFiles))
        fileGenre = getGenre(rawDataPath+filename)
        genresID[fileGenre] = genresID[fileGenre] + 1 if fileGenre in genresID else 1
        fileID = genresID[fileGenre]
        newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+str(fileID)
        createSpectrogram(filename,newFilename)
```

ERROR:

```
Creating spectrograms...
Creating spectrogram for file 1/1...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    createSlicesFromAudio()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DeepAudioClassification/songToData.py", line 72, in createSlicesFromAudio
    createSpectrogramsFromAudio()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DeepAudioClassification/songToData.py", line 66, in createSpectrogramsFromAudio
    newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+str(fileID)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

`fileGenre` is `None` and you can't concatenate `None` with `_` (`str`), as indicated by the exception.

The code seems to be closely related to [this repo](https://github.com/despoisj/DeepAudioClassification/blob/master/songToData.py) and hence `getGenre` is defined as:

```
def getGenre(filename):
    audiofile = eyed3.load(filename)
    #No genre
    if not audiofile.tag.genre:
        return None
    else:
        return audiofile.tag.genre.name.encode('utf-8')
```

As you can see, if no genre is defined, you get `None`. Later it results in the exception.

```
fileGenre = getGenre(rawDataPath+filename) # -> None
genresID[fileGenre] = genresID[fileGenre] + 1 if fileGenre in genresID else 1 # -> 1
fileID = genresID[fileGenre] # whatever
newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+str(fileID) # EXCEPTION
```

It'd seem that your audio files do not have a `genre` tag and hence the error.

Comment: rawDataPath is getting from config file. Do I have to fill in the filename field in this section? I do not understand exactly what to do

Comment: You need to make sure that `getGenre` returns a valid string, as otherwise you get None and the exception. In this case it'd seem that your audio files do not have a `genre` tag and hence the error. What to do? Make sure they have a tag. I'd recommend to go line by line with a debugger.

Comment: @MuratKılınç Did I answer your question? Or you were expecting a more comprehensive solution that makes your code work?